# Xcode 12 (beta) compiler error - two classes with the same name, but in different modules

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm using cocoapods to incorporate two SDKs, both of which internally declare a class named `GeneralRequestError`. This works fine in Xcode 11, but in Xcode 12 I get an error
`'GeneralRequestError' has different definitions in different modules;`.

I could reach out to the SDK creators (actually in this case the two SDKs are from the same company), but I wondered whether there's anything else I've missed - something to force each module into a different namespace or suchlike?

Comment: Having this issue too in Xcode 12. Type of the same name in two different 3rd party modules is breaking the compile. I'm not even using the type in my app.

Comment: Any fix/workaround for this? I was using Xcode 12 for sometime right now then it suddenly had this error.